# Loading an XML file into Word with Content Controls

Tags: xml, ms-word, contentcontrol

I've got a situation where I want to be able to use Word as a Viewer of sorts for XML files that I have defined by an XSD file. I was considering using Content Controls, but I can't find a way to import an XML file into my Word Template (I don't want the end users to have to unzip Word, add the XML file, etc.). Is there any way of doing this? Or writing some type of popup for a Word Document in VBA?

Or, is there an easier way to go about doing this than using Content Controls? I'm aware of XSLT but I haven't had much luck learning how to use XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Missing something, why do you want to use word to view xml? Do you mean you want embed an xml in a word document a la ole?

Comment: I have a large collection of XML files that all follow the same Schema. I want to be able to create a template that my end users (who have no experience in XML/Programming) can use to view the data contained in the XML document.

Comment: Why can't you just throw it up in a browser then?

Comment: What does the XML look like? Whether it is document- or data-oriented would affect the advice.  For example, @bibadiak's comment above about repeating data (which can be overcome).  Before you worry about end users importing your XML file, try using the Content Control toolkit to map your XML, and satisfy yourself that you can get the view you are looking for.